# How to get variable output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
$pg1fa1="52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:00;52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:02;52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:04"
$array_name="storage01"
$a=$array_name.Substring(8) 
Write-Host "pg$($a)fa1"
```

I want output of $pg1fa1 variable but i am getting pg1fa1 as output.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you want? It seems like your question is specific, but the code you are executing looks like you are trying to concatenate variables together.

Comment: what specific output do you want from the code above? it is not at all clear ... [*frown*]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I am new to powersheel. Sorry for not providing proper information.                                                                       I have a variables defined in my script as $pg1fa1 . In this variable middle numeric number will be different and rest naming convention would be same. I will provide input through read-host command and and the last digit of input will be decide what will be the value in that variable "pg$($a)fa1 ".  with write-host i am getting only variable name but i need values of variables. which was solved by get-variable command.

Answer (score 3):

If the name of a variable is variable, pun intended, you can use Get-Variable like in the example below

```
$pg1fa1="52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:00;52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:02;52:4a:93:78:34:06:21:04" 
$array_name="storage01" 
$a=$array_name.Substring(8) 
Write-Host (Get-Variable "pg$($a)fa1").Value
```

Comment: Hi Gert. It's worked and fulfilled my requirement. Thank you.